# (Problem solved) Set the value of a livedata variable of type <data class> to a list of strings?

Tags: kotlin

How to populate the value of this variable:

```
 private val _urlList = MutableLiveData<List<Url>>()
```

of type Url:

```
data class Url(
        val imgSrcUrl: String
)
```

with the incoming list of url strings from a firebase call?

Here is where the magic happens:

```
    private fun getData(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                getImagesUrl {
              "Here where I need to set the value of the variable to a listOf(it) with it being strings 
               of urls retrieved from firebase storage"
                }
            }catch (e: Exception){
             "Handling the error"
            }

        }
    }
```

---

**Edit**

The map function @dominicoder provided solved my problem, answer accepted.
Thank you all for your help

Comment: Not sure I quite understand your question. Sounds like you're trying to set the value of a `LiveData<Url>` to a list of strings?

Comment: @HenryTwist yes. Url being the data class I provided. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Well a `LiveData<Url>` can only hold values of type `Url`? So unless `Url` represents a list of strings then I am not sure what your purpose is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear because you're showing a live data of a single `Url` object but asking to stuff it with a list of strings. So first, your live data object needs to change to a list of `Url`s:

```
private val _urlList = MutableLiveData<List<Url>>()
```

Then, assuming `getImagesUrl` yields a list of strings, if I understood you correctly, then you would map that to a list of `Url`s:

```
getImagesUrl { listOfImageUrlStrings ->
    _urlList.value = listOfImageUrlStrings.map { imageUrlString -> Url(imageUrlString) }
}
```

If that does not answer your question, you really need to review it and clarify.

Comment: Or you can use a function reference to the ``Url`` constructor, ``listOfStrings.map(::Url)`` which is pretty neat. (You have ``URL`` in your answer which is a different class that takes a string, might cause some confusion!)

Answer (score 0):

You can set values on the MutableLiveDataObject in two ways (depends on what you're doing).

Setting the value as normal from the UI thread can be done with:

```
myLiveData.value = myobject
```

If you're setting it from a background thread like you might in a coroutine with a suspended function or async task etc then use:

```
myLiveData.postValue(myObject)
```

It's not clear from your question whether the LiveData is meant to hold a list as you mention both lists and single values. But your LiveData holds a set the values as a collection like a list, set or map. It's can be treated as a whole object so adding a value later needs to have the whole collection set again like:

```
myLiveData.value = mutableListOf<Url>()

//Response received and object created
myLiveData.value = myLiveData.value.apply {
   add(myObject)
}
```

Or if the value is mutable updating the existing value (preferred as it's cleaner):

```
myLiveData.value.add(myObject)
```

The problem with that approach is you're exposing the map as a mutable/writeable object. Allowing accessors to change the values which you might not want.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and sorry if my question was a bit vague. I actually needed a way to map the list of strings result, to the data variable inside the livedata. 
dominicoder solution took care of that ^^
But thanks anyways ^^